# Android on ubuntu with eclipse

Tags: android

I got HTC Desire phone, and i want to be able to run my application (developing ob eclipse or netbeans) on it. But when i run my applications i see (in the list of running devices ??? in 'name' column and ??? in status column. So i can`t press OK button (it`s just disabled). Please tell me how can i make normal synchronization???

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is described here in step 3:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

You have to:

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. Each device manufacturer uses a different vendor ID. The example rules files below show how to add an entry for a single vendor ID (the HTC vendor ID). In order to support more devices, you will need additional lines of the same format that provide a different value for the SYSFS{idVendor} property. For other IDs, see the table of USB Vendor IDs, below.

1. Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

   For Gusty/Hardy, edit the file to read:
     SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

   For Dapper, edit the file to read:
     SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
2. Now execute:
     chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Answer (score 0):

So this means you've followed all the instructions on the android dev site:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#InstallingADT

You should also google "Developing on a Device android dev" (cannot post 2 links!)

My solution is that you need to go (command-line) to "tools" sub-directory in the SDK (that's check step2 in the first link)

Commands to execute:

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
./adb devices
```

this works for me. I have to do it every time I reboot (would love to have a solution for that!).